# Could the use of strict pattern in Matt 12:33-37 show influence of Greek thought?

Tags: jesus, new-testament, parallelism

In Matthew 12:33-37 *("Either make the tree good and its fruit good, or else make the tree bad and its fruit bad ...")* there are 3 precisely patterned pairs. The pattern in each case consists of 2 consecutive clauses where the first one has a word for good in some sense and the second one is identical except that good is replaced with its opposite.

It seems to me that this strict, repetitive pattern is not typical of Hebrew, which uses parallelism, where pairs of similar ideas are placed in sequence with variation in vocabulary. The thought here is similar to Proverbs 14:30 *(A sound heart is life to the body,
But envy is rottenness to the bones*), where parallelism with change of vocabulary is used to show contrast.

Does anyone know enough about the development of Jewish literature to be able to say whether this sort of logical purity is homegrown or from Hellenistic influence?